# JavaScript Velocity do not wait until animation finishes

Tags: javascript, animation, timing

I am using JavaScript with the VelocityJS library to animate a pointer on my screen. The thing is that I get my input for how many degrees I have to rotate the pointer way more often than it can process.

The code that I have right now is:

```
function changePointer(msg){
    kmh = parseInt(msg.payloadString);
    degreesToTurnTo = Math.round(kmh * stapgrote);
    $("#pointer").velocity({
        rotateZ: degreesToTurnTo+"deg"
    });
    console.log(degreesToTurnTo);
}
```

The function is getting called about 5 times a second, but 1 animation already takes about half a second.

So my question is, how can I make an if statements that checks if the previous animation is ready (so that I can update it again once its finished). Or how can I cancel the current animation and start the next one (this method would be preferred since I am making a speedometer).

Thanks in advance!

With kind regards,
Mats de Waard

Answer (score 0):

From: http://velocityjs.org/#stop

```
/* Prior Velocity call. */
$element.velocity({ opacity: 0 });
/* Later, midway through the call... */
$element
    /* Stop animating opacity. */
    .velocity("stop")
    /* Animate opacity back to 1. */
    .velocity("reverse");
```

So in your case something like:

```
$("#pointer")
.velocity("stop")
.velocity({
    rotateZ: degreesToTurnTo+"deg"
});
```